# Sping-Boot Config: How to keep whitespace in yaml key being used to populate Map<String, String>

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

Let's say we have a configuration properties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "whitespace.test")
public class WhitespaceTestConfig {

    private Map<String, String> configs;

    public Map<String, String> getConfigs() {
        return configs;
    }

    public void setConfigs(Map<String, String> configs) {
        this.configs = configs;
    }
}
```

and we try to configure it with a key with space included in it:

```
whitespace.test.configs:
  Key With Whitespace: "I am a value with whitespace in it"
```

Seems as through spring can parse this yaml fine, and it is apparently valid yaml. However, spring (SnakeYaml?) removes the spaces in the Key string:

```
KeyWithWhitespace -> I am a value with whitespace in it
```

An easy solution is to designate a special character for space and replace it within the application, but I was wondering if spring already handled this in some fashion? Perhaps there is a way to escape a space in the config in such a way that spring (SnakeYaml?) knows the we want to keep it, or perhaps there is a way to configure this?

For the sake of completeness I've tried using single and double quotations as well as `\s` `\b`.

**Update:**

After some additional research I found an example from SnakeYaml repository that seems to indicate that what I'm looking for should be possible: https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-block-mappings

Specifically this example:

```
# YAML
base armor class: 0
base damage: [4,4]
plus to-hit: 12
plus to-dam: 16
plus to-ac: 0
```

```
# Java
{'plus to-hit': 12, 'base damage': [4, 4], 'base armor class': 0, 'plus to-ac': 0, 'plus to-dam': 16}
```

In the example the spaces persist in the keys. Unfortunately, I'm at a loss with regard to figuring out where the whitespace is actually getting removed.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the keys with double quotes?

Comment: Yes, that did not work. As in the answer the way to do this is `'[...]'`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For map keys with special characters you need to surround the key with `'[]'` for the key to be used as specified.

So, in your case it will be

```
whitespace.test.configs:
  '[Key With Whitespace]': "I am a value with whitespace in it"
```

Comment: Document: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0#maps

Comment: Note that the single quotes around the key are important.

Answer (score 2):

The new binder is much stricter about property names which means you need to surround them in square brackets. Try the following:

```
shiro:
  testMap:
    "[/test1]": test1
    "[/test2]": test2
```